# Log4j2 log ThreadPoolExecutor uncaughted exception

Tags: java, log4j, threadpool

How to log uncaught exceptions from a ThreadPoolExecutor?

I tried to implement the logging in afterExecute().
It can print the stack trace by printStackTrace() but it doesn't log into a file or console via log4j2.

I am not sure it is a log4j2 issue or my customized ThreadPoolExecutor issue.
Here is my code:

```
package mytest;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class ThreadPoolTest {

    /** logger */
    private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ThreadPoolTest .class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = CommonExecutors.newSingleThreadPoolExecutor(Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LOGGER.debug("start...");
                String str = null;
                str.trim();
                LOGGER.debug("bye!");
            }
        });
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    static class CommonExecutors extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

        public CommonExecutors( //
                int corePoolSize, //
                int maximumPoolSize, //
                long keepAliveTime, //
                TimeUnit unit, //
                BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue //
                ) {
            super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
            LOGGER.debug(t); // printed null, why?
            t.printStackTrace(); // can print the stack trace
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param threadFactory
         * @return
         */
        public static ThreadPoolExecutor newSingleThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
            return new CommonExecutors( //
                    1, //
                    1, //
                    0L, //
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, //
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>() //
            );
        }

    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%t] %p %c{1} - %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="DEBUG" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

output:

```
2019-10-12 20:34:30,772 [pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG ThreadPoolTest - start... 
2019-10-12 20:34:30,774 [pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG ThreadPoolTest - null 
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" 2019-10-12 20:34:30,776 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=1704856573, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2d8f65a4]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mytest.ThreadPoolTest.afterExecute(ThreadPoolTest.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is the thrown exception?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in the description of [ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable)):

> **Note**: When actions are enclosed in tasks (such as FutureTask) either explicitly or via methods such as **submit**, these task objects catch and maintain computational exceptions, and so they do not cause abrupt termination, and the internal exceptions are not passed to this method.

So you should either submit your `Runnable` using

```
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    // ...
});
```

or use the sample code provided in the documentation of [ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable)) to extract the thrown exception:

```
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
  super.afterExecute(r, t);
  if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
    try {
      Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
    } catch (CancellationException ce) {
        t = ce;
    } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        t = ee.getCause();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
    }
  }
  if (t != null)
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact the expected behavior. Quoting the method's [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.Throwable-) shows why this is happening:

> **Note**: When actions are enclosed in tasks (such as FutureTask) either
>   explicitly or via methods such as submit, these task objects catch and
>   maintain computational exceptions, and so they do not cause abrupt
>   termination, and the internal exceptions are not passed to this
>   method.

In you case the `NullPointerException` is not an not an exception that caused an abrupt end of the submitted task. So based, on the behavior of the method the exception will never be passed into the `afterExecute` method (hence the null throwable).

This is even easier to grasp and understand if you debug your code and check on the content of the `Runnable` in the method. Doing so you'll see that outcome of the `FutureTask` is a `NullPointerException`.

I suppose you can intercept the outcome of the task and log it if you really need to.